# Queries in Rails views - what's the most efficient way to repeat one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a few instances on a page where I need to know if the current_user has a 'tlk_with_me' rich text attachment. For example:

```
<%= current_user.tlk_with_me.present? ? 'update-class' : 'leave-class' %>

<%= f.submit "#{ current_user.tlk_with_me.present? ? 'Update' : 'Leave' } Your Details"... %>

<% if current_user.tlk_with_me.present? %>
  <p class="create-remove-details">...</p>
<% end %>
```

I don't know much about the deep details of Rails, but I'm wondering if it is more efficient to do this or to set a variable in the view (or controller).

For example:

```
<% current_user.tlk_with_me.present? ? @twm_present = true : @twm_present = false %>
```

And then to build my views using this boolean; e.g.:

```
<%= @twm_present ? 'update-class' : 'leave-class' %>
```

It would be great to learn more about Rails through getting an answer to this question. Thank you.

Comment: You could move this into a controller so you only set the variable once instead of repeating it in the various views.  I suppose you could also make it a method on the user too.  Depending on where you needed it you could either set it in the application controller (if you need it pretty much everywhere) or just in the controller in charge of these views.  And then in the view, you would have access to the values already.

Comment: Is there a difference in efficiency between these two or does it not matter really?

Comment: Not scattering database queries all over your views lets you avoid performance problems down the line. Your views should just ideally take data from the controller and just render it into HTML in the simplest way possible. Views in themselves are really messy since you are mixing HTML and embedded ruby tags. I consider setting variables in the view a code smell.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense to me

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to add a method to your User model:

```rb
class User
  def twm?
    tlk_with_me.present?
  end 
end
```

That way you can write `<%= current_user.twm? ? 'update-class' : 'leave-class' %>`

I would not worry about efficiency of calling this multiple times, unless it is a network call, then you should cache it.

Comment: I don't know what `tlk_with_me` is or does. If it is a database column or an association then you don't need to cache it. But it could be something that you get by making a request to another server (that's a network call), that could be time consuming and thus worth caching.